# problems with sequence code in controller

Tags: laravel, controller

The `$trendtag` code alone works. However it doesnt get posts if I want to load the posts.

If I run `dd($tagIdArray)`, I get the `id`'s of the tags. But the following code has no function. If I do not use $trendtags, or only like this, it works:

```
$trendtags = Taggable::take(3)
            ->with('tag')
            ->get();
```

But how can I find the most used tags in the last 48 Hours?

Is there another way?

```
$trendtags = Taggable::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subHours(48))
            ->groupBy('tag_id')
            ->orderByRaw('count(tag_id) DESC')
            ->take(3)
            ->with('tag')
            ->get();

        $tagIdArray = $trendtags->pluck('id')->all();

    $article = Article::with('comments', 'tags')
      ->whereIn('privacy', [1, 2])
      ->where('status', 1)
      ->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagIdArray) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $tagIdArray);
      }, '>=', count($tagIdArray))
      ->latest()
      ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Is `Taggable` a model from a `pivot_table`. If so, should you not be using `Tag` (model) instead? Then check `whereHas()` `article` where `pivot->created_at` is within this time?

Comment: Why do you `take(3)` and then do `with('tag')`? You should know that order matters here.